# Creating an interface of FileStream.Open c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create an interface of the FileStream.Open method. I have started but have got a little confused:

```
public interface IFileDataSource
{
    FileStream Open(string path,
                 FileMode mode,
                 FileAccess access,
                 FileShare share);
}
```

Do I need to wrap this is another class to be able to use this interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to "wrap" it - but you do need to *implement* it in order to use it. Presumably you'd write a simple implementation which just delegates to `File.Open`:

```
public class BclFileDataSource : IFileDataSource
{
    public FileStream Open(string path,
                           FileMode mode,
                           FileAccess access,
                           FileShare share)
    {
        return File.Open(path, mode, access, share);
    }
}
```